# Group by and join in django models

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
  creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
  topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
  image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts')
  ratings = GenericRelation(Rating)


class Rating(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = GenericForeignKey()

  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ratings')
  value = models.SmallIntegerField(default=None, validators=[
      MinValueValidator(DISLIKE_VALUE),
      MaxValueValidator(LIKE_VALUE)
  ])
```

I want to execute the following SQL statement as Django query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.topic_id, SUM(r.value) 
  FROM api_post p 
  JOIN api_rating r 
  ON p.id=r.object_id
  WHERE r.content_type_id=18 
  GROUP BY p.id 
  LIMIT 5;
```

I read through the documentation and the closest I get is this:

```
Post.objects.annotate(rating=Sum('ratings__value')).order_by('ratings').values('id', 'title', 'description', 'rating')
```

Also I don't really want only these fields from the model because it returns them in a dictionary and I would like it to be in a object.